# How to test that in async thread method was invoked?

Tags: java, asynchronous, junit, mockito, powermock

I have following classes:

```
public class ForTest {
    public void methodToTest(Thread thread){
        thread.start();
    }
}
class MyThread extends Thread{
    FooClass fooClass;
    public MyThread(FooClass fooClass){
        this.fooClass = fooClass;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fooClass.bar();
    }
}
class FooClass{
    public void bar(){}
}
```

I want to test method `methodToTest`.
I want to pass instance of MyThread as argument of mentioned method.

As a result I want to verify that method `bar` was invoked.

Can you help me to write it using Mockito or Powermock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to consider:

1. Because you are using external thread, **some kindof waiting/blocking is necessary**.
2. If the thread code is more complicated and because we need to wait for the thread to finish its execution generally speaking (not your case), it will be necessary to use timeout functionality.
3. **You don't have to use mocks at all**, e.g. the `FooClass.bar()` method can set/modify a field which will be then checked for a changed value.

   ```
   @Test
   public void testSomeMethod() throws InterruptedException {
       FooClass fooClassMock = Mockito.mock(FooClass.class);
       Thread thread = new MyThread(fooClassMock);

       new ForTest().methodToTest(thread);

       thread.join();

       Mockito.verify(fooClassMock).bar();
   }
   ```

Comment: I believe that I shouldn't use timeout.

Comment: Well it depends. In your case as it is a trivial code you really don't have to use `timeout` parameter as the thread execution will be very fast.

Comment: But generally if the thread execution can be longer and more complicated, `@Test(timeout...)` should always be used.

Comment: Use of threads does not imply timeouts should be used. Provided the code is expected to terminate, then it is like any other application code. I also don't understand why you've stated "*You don't have to use mocks at all"*, then provided a code sample which uses mocking. Your sample looks good though, but I'm refraining from a +1 until some of the other confusing stuff is addressed.